# Does a pardoning a crime "undo" punishment which has already occurred as part of the convict's sentence?

Tags: pardon

In the USA, if someone is pardoned or has their sentence commuted, does this have any effect on any aspects of their sentencing that have already been carried out?

For example, [this article](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/02/18/us/politics/trump-pardons.html?action=click&module=Top%20Stories&pgtype=Homepage) states the following about one person recently pardoned by President Trump:

> In 2010, Paul Pogue, the founder and former chief executive of a large
>   construction company in Texas, was sentenced to three years of
>   probation and was ordered to pay $723,0000 in fines and restitution
>   for filing false income tax statements

Would the $723K fine in this example be returned due to the pardon? Taking it further, could a pardonee then claim against the government for, say, lost wages for the duration of imprisonment? etc.

If it were a commutation instead of a pardon, would that change anything?

Comment: see a number of answers @ https://www.justice.gov/pardon/frequently-asked-questions  the question of fines is addressed wrt commutations, not pardons.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica thanks - I think you should add that as an answer because its an actual reference which is quite objective. Even if it only partially addresses the question (wrt pardons)

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference and it's mostly how the legal fiction handles the situation.

In the case of a Pardon by the President (or State Governor for state crimes), a Pardon will be treated as if the trial happened but the pardoned person was never convicted.  Essentially it declares a formerly guilty by conviction is now an aquittal and the sentence is no longer valid to hold the person other, nor any restrictions on civil rights (i.e. You cannot legally buy a firearm if you're convicted of any crime in the U.S.   If you're pardoned, this right is restored.).  It's not even uncommon for a President to wait out the full sentence of the convicted then pardon him, which essentially means the recipient will serve his full sentence, but then expunges his record of any wrong doing (This tactic was favored by Bush if I recall my history correctly). The fact that the trial verdict is overturned is important because it keeps the pardoned person from being convicted when the next administration comes into office, as it would be a violation of the protections against Double Jeopardy.

A commutation, on the other hand, will still treat the outcome of trial as a guilty conviction but overturns the sentence for a less severe one.  It need not mean that a commutation recipient gets a get out of jail card, as a governor or president may commute a death row inmate's sentence to life in prison (especially if they are in favor of abolishing capitol punishment).  It's a compromise for the executive officer in that it balances that these people committed a crime that needs to be punished, but the punishment handed by the judge was overly harsh and the administration doesn't want to hold him for that long.

Trumps use of pardons is unusual in that he is not issuing them while he is a lame duck President.  The main strategy is to hold off on pardoning or commuting sentences until after the November election but before the Inauguration of a new president.  This shelters the President and his party from unpopular pardons (there's always one) affecting the outcome of the election for both the President (if he can run for another term) and his party (running for congress and the guy he's probably gonna vote for if he can't run for another term).   Who the previous President pardoned two years ago is not a big vote winner in the mid-terms, the next earliest time for the nation to make a choice on the matter.  Though not a hard rule (I'm pretty sure other modern presidents pardoned and commuted people prior to becoming a lame duck) it's just most of his pardons in this manner are high profile.

Finally, the Presidential Pardon of the Turkeys is a moment for the president to be a little silly as most Presidents use the event to poke fun at pardons and Washington politics (Trump's recent turkey pardon allowed him to mock the Houses Impeachment hearings, though your mileage as to how funny it was varies.   Obama's first 7 turkey pardons allowed him ample time to engage in what I would argue is his greatest Presidential Past Time - being an Overly Embarrassing  Parent to his teenage daughters on national television... and his 8th turkey pardon was more of pardoning his noticeably absent daughters from the cruel and unusual sentence of standing in full camera view of their dad making Thanksgiving Dad jokes on national television.).

Comment: My understanding of _Burdick v. United States_ was that a pardon carries with it an implicit admission of guilt, not by formally or informally changing a guilty verdict to a not guilty verdict after the fact. Some states may not restore voting rights or other rights to those pardoned of felonies, I know in NC they didn't restore firearm rights until a superior appeals court case in 2013.

Comment: @JeffLambert I'm only working with Federal Pardons, but I included the governors because the fact that Obama could not pardon the two subjects of the "Making a Murder" series was due to the issue that the Governor of Wisconsin would be the authority to petition, as it was not a Federal Crime.

Comment: A pardon does not mean a person was acquitted. It just means the person has been forgiven criminally. The fine paid are only remitted if the President also orders it to be so as far as I understand. Pardoned crimes can still in some circumstances even be used to impeach credibility of witnesses in later trials.

Comment: The discussion of double jeopardy is incorrect.  The next administration cannot prosecute someone after a pardon because of the pardon itself.  The pardon protects the pardoned person from prosecution even if there has not yet been a trial; Richard Nixon is probably the most famous example of this.